# How to make row bind with more than 2 tables using prosql in SAS

Tags: merge, sas, row

I have multiple tables like `Table1` `Table2` `Table3`, `Table4`
They have the same columns in the same order. I want to bind them vertically
I have no idea of how to make it.
I tried this code:

```
PROC SQL; 

    create table Table_final AS

    ( 

    select * from Table1 

    union all

    select * Table2 
    
    union all

    select * Table3 
  
    union all

    select * Table4 

    ); 

    QUIT;
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Any reason you can't use the SAS data step?  It does this much more easily...

Comment: I am doing a query on database. Can I use a code other than ```PROC SQL```

Comment: Sure.  Show more details of what your code would look like, with the libnames/connect to/etc. in there.

Comment: How does it not work?  Did you get error messages? post the log.  Wrong results? Explain how it is wrong.

Comment: Thanks to everyone; I solve the problem otherly (by the longest way), by binding the tables two by two; thats is I bound the two first tables then I bound the third one to the created table and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glad you solved the problem by yourself in an alternate way. However you made few syntax errors by ignoring `FROM` statement on your query.

Here is your updated code:

```
PROC SQL; 
create table Table_final AS
 ( 
    select * from Table1 
    union all
    select * from Table2     
    union all
    select * from Table3   
    union all
    select * from Table4 
 ); 
QUIT;
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

SQL or data steps are not super efficient as they process the data line by line. Instead the fastest method is to combine them one at a time using PROC APPEND. This copies the data block by block rather than one line at a time. Note that the Base table does not need to exist before this procedure.

```
proc append base=table_final data=data1;
run;
proc append base=table_final data=data2;
run;
proc append base=table_final data=data3;
run;
```